# Display "No Results" message with jQuery checkbox filter

Tags: jquery, forms

I found a jQuery filter that works really well for my needs (http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/171/). My only issue is that I want it to display a "No results found" message when the filtered results do not produce a result.

```
    var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.flower');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.flower').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

});
```

If you use the Fiddle to select both "Red" and "Africa", the results show blank. An ideal UX would be to say "No results found, try changing your filters."

How can I accomplish this with the provided code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the css class for hide

```
.hide{display:none; }
```

Add this div at the bottom of all your .flowers div

```
<div id="NoResult" class="hide" >No results found, try changing your filters.</div>
```

Add this inside your change event

```
if(!$('.flower').is(':visible'))
 {
  $("#NoResult").removeClass("hide");
 }
 else
 {
 $("#NoResult").addClass("hide");
 
 }
```

Here is the altered fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r97L1zvf/1/